# pattern recognition in time series with rnn

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, pattern-recognition, recurrent-neural-network

The data I am using is the raw data of UCI human activities dataset. The following figure shows the 13 labels(top) and 6 features(bottom) of an example. I want to develop a model to automatically detect the different patterns/activities from the time series with 6 features.

[example of the training data and its labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugL6p.png)

I have two questions now hope someone can help me:
1. if I have all the time series data that needs to be labeled (I want to detect the patterns in the time series), what model can I use? Can I use CNN for this task, like object detection in images? or should I use RNN? Is there any similar projects that I can refer to?
2. if the data is collected in real time and I want to detect the patterns in real time (or with small lag), how can I do this?

I have tried to use LSTM to classify the pre-processed data segments (2.56s per segment, each segment has one label), and I have achieved 90%+ accuracy without much tuning (Modified from [this repo](https://github.com/guillaume-chevalier/LSTM-Human-Activity-Recognition), fundamentally the same). However, I am not sure how to apply this model in the situations I mentioned above.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Please edit you question to add what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have added a link to a github repo

Comment: @Bing can you describe briefly the nature of your input features?

Comment: @Maxim the input features were tri-axial signals collected from accelerator and gyroscope at 50 HZ. The input data has been de-noised and normalized. All of the input data has also been properly labeled. More details can be found here(https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/human+activity+recognition+using+smartphones)